# How to handle where bracket with OR codition?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to filter with **Free Text** that mean user can type anything they want to filter. So, when user type in side the input as I put below. So, I want to filter them by following this logic.

```
Free text = "abc def,ghi jkl"
...
AND
(
    (report.name like '%abc%'  AND report.name like '%def%')
    OR
    (bom_functions.name like '%abc%'  AND bom_functions.name like '%def%')
    OR
    (report.name like '%ghi%' AND report.name like '%jkl%')
    OR
    (bom_functions.name like '%ghi%' AND bom_functions.name like '%jkl%')
)
```

Can anyone help me out!

Comment: Please elaborate on your question a little bit better. your question is very vague and ambiguous.

Comment: Sir, @AhmadKarimi I have updated my question. Could you check it?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code it should work

```
$model->where(function ($query) {

        return $query
            ->where(function ($a) {
                return $a
                    ->where('report.name', 'like', '%abc%')
                    ->where('report.name', 'like', '%def%');
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($b) {
                return $b
                    ->where('bom_functions.name', 'like', '%abc%')
                    ->where('bom_functions.name', 'like', '%def%');
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($c) {
                return $c
                    ->where('report.name', 'like', '%abc%')
                    ->where('report.name', 'like', '%def%');
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($d) {
                return $d
                    ->where('bom_functions.name', 'like', '%ghi%')
                    ->where('bom_functions.name', 'like', '%jkl%');
            });
    });
```

[Reference:Logical Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get your question correctly but i think this can help you.
You can use `orWhere` in Laravel

```
$freetext = "abc def,ghi jkl"
....
where(function ($query) use ($freetext) {
   $query->orWhere('report.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $freetext . '%')
         ->orWhere('bom_functions.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $freetext . '%')
}
```